# PowerMock not ripping off java final class modifier

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, final, powermock

Trying to mock a final class using Mockito and PowerMock I'm getting the error :

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class MyFinalClass
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:447)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
```

this happens inside a huge project, then to isolate from weird effects I've just extracted MyFinalClass class into a little test project and now I'm able to mock it.

Doing some research I also found that the problem is getting the class for passing it to PowerMock

```
    final MyFinalClass mock = PowerMockito.mock(MyFinalClass.class);
```

because doing it inside my huge project and obtaining modifiers it's shown as public and final :

```
    MyFinalClass.class.getModifiers() == 17
```

but doing it inside my little test project it is shown as public only :

```
    MyFinalClass.class.getModifiers() == 1
```

Because getModifiers() method is native I can't debug inside it and see what is happening.

Any clue what can be causing **this class modifiers not to be changed by PowerMock and left as a final class** ? or how can I discover why PowerMock not working as expected **inside my huge project** ?

Comment: @Steven That's why he's using Powermock.  Powermock messes with your bytecode, so that you're not actually testing what you _think_ you're testing.  It looks like this has included changing a `final` class to non-final.

Comment: Agreed and happy that it works this way **but** the problem is about why this doesn't happen inside my _huge project_